# Conditional time display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timestamp

In the mailbox section of my Rails app, I simply display the timestamps of each message as follows:

```
<%= message.created_at.utc %>
```

But I want to change it so that if the message's date is different to today, then display the date, otherwise just display the time (e.g. like Gmail).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting something like this in a helper:

```
def time_or_date(date)
  date.today? ? date.strftime('%H:%M') : date.strftime('%d/%m')
end
```

You can then call it from your view like this:

```
<%= time_or_date(message.created_at.utc) %>
```

You might want to change *strftime* so it fits your needs:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000297